# User attributes for OIDC standard claims using Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, claims-based-identity, idp

I am using Keycloak as an identity provider for an application. The users can create an account directly via Keycloak and the users are required fill some personal information that maps to [OIDC standard claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#StandardClaims) when registering.

I added the attributes I wanted in the "User profile" in the Realm settings. However, this step is not straightforward as there is no 1:1 mapping between the Keycloak standard attributes and the OIDC standard claims. For example, Keycloak standard theme and translations expect a `firstName` attribute while OIDC uses a `given_name` claim.

This is better illustrated with the configured attributed in Keycloak:
[image: user profile attributes]

For a particular user, Keycloak maps these attributes to a set of OIDC claims:

```json
{
  "address": {
    "street_address": "Downtown Alley 12a",
    "locality": "London",
    "postal_code": "12345",
    "country": "UK"
  },
  "birthdate": "1950-01-01",
  "gender": "male",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "email": "john@example.com"
}
```

However, I had to create these attributes in a trial-and-error process. For the display name, I used the [translation keys](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f578f91a0b439cf6325185918a26ccb9ed6eaee2/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/messages/messages_en.properties#L76-L105).

Is there a better way to create attributes for OIDC standard claims? Moreover, is this possible to adapt the registration fields to the type and constraints that are expected (e.g. a date for birthdate, a dropdown list for gender) without creating a custom theme and without adding custom validators? I think I am doing this the wrong way.

Comment: Looks like you are using ["Declarative User Profile is Technology Preview"](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#user-profile) which is brand new and disabled by default. Should probably state that in Q. Re "there is no 1:1 mapping between the Keycloak standard attributes and the OIDC standard claims", there sort of is in legacy. The scope mappers for OIDC scopes map user attributes. So for example if you define a user attribute named "picture" it will be mapped to id token when OIDC "profile" scope is requested.